# Pass the text from dd to the input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to pass the text from dd to the input value, but I can't figure out how I can manage this.

Here is the code in HTML:

```
<dd>
<dt class="Phone">Phone:</dt>
<dd class="Phone"><p>+995595858567</p>
</dd>

<input type="text" name="phone2" class="phone2" id="phone2 value=""></input>
```

Here is the jQuery code I'm using:

```
$('dd.Phone').ready(function() {
    $('#phone2').text($(this).text());
});
```

I need this to happen instantly (not on click or change and etc.)

I'm very bad in JS so please could you give me any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure that you can do a document ready on something other than window or document.  But you do have an error in your markup with your input.  Your id field is missing a closing quote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've just to put the code directly in the ready function :

```
$(function() {
    $('#phone2').val($('dd.Phone').text());
});
```

**NOTE 1:** You've a quote `"` typo in your input code also it sholdn't end with `</input>`:

```
<input type="text" name="phone2" class="phone2" id="phone2 value=""></input>
__________________________________________________________^ //Missing quote here
```

Should be :

```
<input type="text" name="phone2" class="phone2" id="phone2" value=""/>
```

**NOTE 2:** input has no `text()` method use `val()` instead to set the value.

Hope this helps.

Comment: DOM ready not strictly needed if the code followed the DOM elements in the page. There was also a broken ID tag

Answer (score 1):

You've got two problems. The first is that `<input type="text" />` is self closing (notice the `/>` at the end as oppose to the need for a `</input>` tag.

Second, in terms of inputs, you'll need to set the `.value` property, not the `.textContent` property. For this, in jQuery, you'll want to use `.val()`:

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
  $('#phone2').val($('dd.Phone p').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dl>
  <dt class="Phone">Phone:</dt>
  <dd class="Phone"><p>+995595858567</p></dd>
</dl>

<input type="text" name="phone2" class="phone2" id="phone2" value="" />
```

**EDIT:**

The commenters were too fast for me. Thank you to *@MikeMcCaughan*, *@GoneCoding* and *@Taplar* who had excellent additions to the answer.

As *@MikeMcCaughan* notes, depending on your usage of XHTML vs HTML5, it is also plausible to use `<input type="text">` without the closing slash `/>` <-- seen here.

As *@GoneCoding* mentioned in his comment, the input element was missing a closing double parenthesis to close out the `id` attribute on the `input` field.

In addition, I corrected the HTML markup. I don't believe it is valid to have a `<dd>` or a `<dt>` nested inside another `<dd>`. Also, the inner `<dd>` was not closed properly `</dd>`.

Comment: You can do `<input type="text">`; you just can't have an end tag.

Comment: ... *and* the ID value is broken (missing quotes)

Comment: That was from @Taplar at the top. I was just the messenger :)

Comment: @GoneCoding I can give them a nod as well. :) I appreciate all the feedback on the answer. Since several people contributed to this answer, it seems only fair for me to mark it as a community wiki. Feel free to add any other additions that you may have.